Is @import reloaded for every shadow DOM it is used in?
I am considering using either native web components or a thin library like Lit that uses web components to componentize my web application. It's an ASP Core app so I want something lightweight, that has a small footprint and no separate client build process.
The only downside is that CSS encapsulation prevents my application css from applying to my components. After some research I have found a technique that seems useable, but I'm concerned that it might have performance implications.
Given a web component defined like this:
class UsingGlobalStyles extends HTMLElement {
   constructor() {
      super();

      this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" }).innerHTML = `
         <style>
            @import "/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
            @import "/css/site.css";
         </style>
         <button class="btn btn-outline-dark">Using global styles</button>
      `;
   }
}

customElements.define("using-global-styles", UsingGlobalStyles);

If I apply this pattern to all the components in my application, would that mean that Bootstrap and my application css are being reloaded for every web component on the page, and if so, how bad is that performance wise?
If this is not performant, is there a different web component based strategy I could use to achieve the same thing? I'm already aware of inherited HTML properties, custom CSS properties and shadow DOM parts, and don't consider any of those to be remotely effective solutions.
Or would I be better off just forgetting about using web components for this purpose and use Vue or some other component framework that doesn't require a separate build step instead?

Like any URI in the browser; when its the same URI and you have not disabled caching, then the CSS files are cached. Easily tested by making your  add another <using-global-styles> Element to the DOM and see what happens in de Dev Console Network tab. Note: years ago some of Bootstrap stuff didn't support  shadowDOM; don't know what the current status is, I don't use it... 35 KB is a bit bloated

I know the file won't be downloaded again. That's not what I asked. I'm wondering whether the repeated @imports will cause overhead as the file is loaded by the browser into each shadow DOM. I've seen some suggestions on the web that @import is best avoided for performance reasons and wanted more info on this.
